# Android - Open browser with a url with request headers

Tags: android

I have a specific requirement where I have to fire a url on the browser from my activity. I am able to do this with the following code :

```
String finalUrl = "http://localhost:7001/display/result.jsp?param=12345";
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse(finalUrl));
```

Now, I want to invoke result.jsp by passing 'param' as a request header in the request and not as the queryString itself.

Can somebody please advice ?

Thanks a lot in advance

**EDIT**
Even a POST request with the 'param' in the request body should be fine.

**EDIT 2**
The accepted answer is for the POST request, not for the headers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Android Browser support 'viewing' javascript, for example the following code can launch the Browser app to show an alert dialog:

```
    String finalUrl = "javascript:alert('hello')";
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            Uri.parse(finalUrl));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
```

A common trick to do post operation by javascript is that you create a form by javascript and then submit it. So in theory code like below should work (part of the code is copied from [this post](http://mentaljetsam.wordpress.com/2008/06/02/using-javascript-to-post-data-between-pages/)):

```
    //String finalUrl = "http://localhost:7001/display/result.jsp?param=12345";
    String finalUrl = "javascript:" + 
        "var to = 'http://localhost:7001/display/result.jsp';" +
        "var p = {param:'12345',param2:'blablabla',param3:'whatever'};"+
        "var myForm = document.createElement('form');" +
        "myForm.method='post' ;" +
        "myForm.action = to;" +
        "for (var k in p) {" +
            "var myInput = document.createElement('input') ;" +
            "myInput.setAttribute('type', 'text');" +
            "myInput.setAttribute('name', k) ;" +
            "myInput.setAttribute('value', p[k]);" +
            "myForm.appendChild(myInput) ;" +
        "}" +
        "document.body.appendChild(myForm) ;" +
        "myForm.submit() ;" +
        "document.body.removeChild(myForm) ;";
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            Uri.parse(finalUrl));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Comment: Works absolutely fine... Thanks a ton Mr. Ziteng... Saved me a lot of time and stress :)