# android.permission.INTERNET removed by Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions

I was uploding my first App to the Google Play Store.
It includes a android.permission.INTERNET permission which worked fine localy.
In the Developer Console i can see that the app uses this permission, but while installing it says that the app don't need special permissions.

When the app opens a webpage with the standard browser, it pops up but no page opens..
instead just the last opened tab is shown.

Am i missing something important here?

Cheers, Andreas

Comment: You should not need INTERNET permission to open standard browser in new window.

Comment: Well, but to receive webpages from the internet i guess. At least i needed while debugging with ADT and hardware phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `android.permission.INTERNET` is used by so many apps, Google moved it to the **Other** category. Permissions in this category are not shown to the user when installing.  You can confirm that the installed app has this permission from looking at it in Settings->Apps.

The blank page in your browser is caused by something else.

Comment: I see, you're right, the permission is there. So i have to take a close look what happens with my intent when i'm back at home.. But strange..in ADT with my old Sony Arc it was working just fine. Thank you anyway, Andreas

Answer (score 0):

So, what i figured out..
As i submit post data using javascript.. (like at https://stackoverflow.com/a/12891955/4110640 )
it seems that this is no longer working since at least 4.2.2, maybe earlier.
I will change to an WebView to support newer devices.

Thanks for the help.